# How to change 1 word in a long String?

Tags: java

I want to change only the value "19" to "23" within the `String`:

```
String text = "hiMyNameIsAnnaIam19YearsOld;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: The answer greatly depends on whether you want a general solution or a specific one.

Comment: text.replace("19", "23")

Comment: please accept one of the answers if they solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method for strings called replace. That matches a specific string.

```
text.replace("19", "23");
```

There is a method for strings called [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). This matches a regex pattern.

```
str.replaceAll(Regex, "X");
```

(You have to build a regular expression. X will replace whatever the regex matches)
So to change 19 to 23. you would do this:

```
text.replaceAll("19", "23");
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

difference between these two methods is: the replace method, you know the string you are looking to replace, and the replaceall method, you don't.

Comment: But if i dont know what is the `"qlt=?"` how can i change only the value come after the word `qlt=` ?

Comment: The reason why qlt=70 was there was because the original poster wanted to match that in her original question. She changed it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. if i want to change multiple words? in one sentence

Comment: @Anna you have to create a regular expression to match the pattern you are looking for. I can write you the regular expression but I need you to tell me how many digits are after qlt= or maybe what is after the digits or another pattern I can match on.

Comment: @A.sharif Ok. the best example is i have a simple `url` e.g `https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?&id=JN.rv2pGmhCfX2zPCIPcaBcDg&w=300&h=300&c=0&pid=1.9&rs=0&p=0` this is a picture url from bing. but only if i change the `qlt` value the image change the quality and i want to change to `w` and the `h` too.
And i hope i can get the `h` and the `w` value too. if it is possible.

Comment: str.replaceAll("w=\d*", "w=200"); (For the width) .
str.replaceAll("h=\d*", "h=200"); (For the height).
str.replaceAll("qlt=\d*", "qlt=200"); (For QLT) .
I am assuming that all the characters after the "=" for these are numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81692/discussion-between-a-sharif-and-anna).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a replace method of string , and then sign the result to  `text` variable

```
text = text.replace("19", "23")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do follows:
text.replaceAll("19", "23");

You can prefer here:
[Docs for replaceAll method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))